# Kafka output stream

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I've been working with the kafka consumer- and producer api for a while now and want to try my hand at the streams api. I've looked at a ton of references online but I cant figure out this one simple thing.

How do you make a KStream that only sends messages to an output topic.

Take for instance this most basic example they have on the github repo:
https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/blob/3.2.x/kafka-streams/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/WordCountLambdaExample.java It takes messages from one queue and posts them to a different one after manipulating it.

Something like this:

```
final KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();
final KStream<String, String> textLines = builder.stream();
// do the dirty work...
textLines.to("outputTopic")
```

But `builder.stream();` does not exists it needs at the very least a input topic name.

Should I just stick to a regular kafka producer for this? If so I have had no luck finding a resource that says this explicitly.

Comment: I am wondering, what you want to do in the "dirty work" part. I would like to understand your use case scenario you have in mind.

Comment: I have data comming in form an external source. Some of these need to get sent to a specific topic after performing some filtering. My idea was to leverage the kstream, because in the future the messages might also come in through kafka and hence i could easily refactor it to use a input topic. Instead of having to now make a provider and later mover over.

Comment: You can use Kafka Connect for this -- it allows to do "single message transformations" including filtering: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_transforms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kafka Streams API is designed to consume topics as input streams, process the records, and write the results back to topics. It's not designed to just write data to Kafka.

So yes, you should use `KafkaProducer` if you want to write data to a topic.

Comment: Is there any specific reason for this? Just wondering if there is something fundamental I am missing about the api. I expected as much though.

Comment: Streams is designed to process data that is stored in Kafka :) However, you can use Kafka Connect for this -- it allows to do "single message transformations" including filtering: kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_transforms